# I have change code in android studio but changes is not show in mobile devices

Tags: android

I have done Invalidate cache, clean project, rebuild project, add gradle make aware but still problem remains the same.

Comment: Can you share what is the error facing?

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: does not show any error.

Comment: You can try to disable instant run if you use it. Other thing is you can try to re-import your whole project.

Comment: Last time I had this problem because of the logic of my code, not android studio problem so you need to provide us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio thinks that there are no changes and doesn't install the new APK. A workaround is to disable the `"Skip installation if APK has not changed"` option in

> Run > Edit Configurations >Android Application > app >Miscellaneous .

Then uncheck **"Skip installation if APK has not changed"**

[image]

Another problem like this is instant Run you can manage it by :- Just go to

> "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> Instant Run"

and just disable it. With this Android Studio builds from scratch each time but it's better than not building it right.